# Can we use maven surefire plugin to execute testcases present in the source directory

Tags: maven

The Java project I am working on is a list of testcases written in Java for testing C++ code. So I want to run the testcases from the src directory in the test phase of the maven lifecycle. How do I configure the maven surefire plugin to achieve this.

Comment: Why not using a C++ unit test framework ? Like boost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is Java based tests that presumably will not be part of the production code, I suggest that you follow [Maven's standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and move the tests to the `src/test/java` directory as usual (otherwise, the tests will be part of the binary file if someone executes `mvn package`).